# Error al iniciar mysql xampp, no se conecta al puerto

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, windows, servidor, xampp

Al iniciar mi xampp, me indica el siguiente error

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
13:54:13  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
13:54:13  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
13:54:13  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
13:54:13  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
13:54:13  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
13:54:13  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

me deriva a un log donde está el siguiente texto, alguien me puede indicar como solucionar el error, no he modificado nada apareció de un dia para otro.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-09-18 13:53:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-09-18 13:53:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-09-18 13:53:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-09-18 13:53:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-09-18 13:53:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-09-18 13:53:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-09-18 13:53:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 3629068354; transaction id 53706
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-18 13:54:11 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200918 13:54:11
2020-09-18 13:54:12 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Otro programa debe estar utilizando ese puerto; lo puedes cambiar desde el panel de control de Xampp.

Comment: cambia de puerto. Por lo general mysql usa el puerto `8080`. Tal vez alguna aplicación lo esta usando.

Comment: El servidor si se inicia, lo que no se inicia es la base de datos, ya he cambiado el puerto de la base de datos también, pero el error persiste